# Pointers not holding values in C

Tags: c, file, pointers, reference

I am trying to get a list of values to update when this code is run but I am at my wit's end. The output is correct within the readFile() function, however, it is wrong in the main() function for PY2014 and I cannot figure out why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void readFile(char *myFile, int *firstYear, int *secondYear,
                         int *thirdYear, int PY2014[]) {
int firstThree[3];
int i = 0;

FILE *fp = fopen(myFile, "r");

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &firstThree[i]);
}

*firstYear = firstThree[0];
*secondYear = firstThree[1];
*thirdYear = firstThree[2];

PY2014 = (int*)calloc(*firstYear, sizeof(int));

for (i = 0; i < firstThree[0]; i++) {
    fscanf(fp, "%d", (PY2014 + i));
}

for (i = 0; i < *firstYear; i++) {
    printf("PY2014 Function: %d\n", PY2014[i]);
}

fclose(fp);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    int init1 = 2, init2 = 3, init3 = 4, init4[10];
    int *firstYear = &init1;
    int *secondYear = &init2;
    int *thirdYear = &init3;
    int *PY2014 = init4;


    readFile(argv[2], firstYear, secondYear, thirdYear, PY2014);

    printf("firstYear : %d\n", *firstYear);
    printf("secondYear : %d\n", *secondYear);
    printf("thirdYear : %d\n", *thirdYear);

    for (int i = 0; i < *firstYear; i++) {
        printf("PY2014: %d\n", *(PY2014+i));
    } 
}
```

The input file I am giving it is a list of integers each separated by a newLine. For example, if the .txt file holds 
    8
    15
    15
    59
    154
    266
    435
    267
    -5
    21
    269
The code should read the last 8 values after the first 3 into PY2014. When I run it currently, the print loop in readFile gets the correct numbers, but when the loop is called in main() it is only zeros.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tour You can take a look at this first - to know how the site works (As you are a new here).

Comment: If you want to change `PY2014` in `readFile`, you have to pass in the address of `PY2014`. Your `readFile` should accept `int **`. Currently, `PY2014` is just a local pointer and you are actually leaking memory.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you are passing a pointer and then you allocate memory and assign the address of it to the passed pointer. And then the scope ends and the changes made to the local pointer variable in the called function is lost. You try to print some un-initialized value in `main()`. In your case it turns out to be zero.(Garbage values).

If your intention was to make changes to the array you could have passed the array and make change to it. You passed a pointer which contains the address of the array (which was not needed). If you had passed the array  to a function, the array decays into pointer variable. Any change made to the pointer variable would be enough to retain the changes.

In your case solution would be to remove the `calloc`. That solves the problem. As you didn't free the allocated memory that memory is leaked. Also remember that whenever you allocate some memory dynamically - free it when you are done working with it.

#### Codewise(Solution):

```
...
*secondYear = firstThree[1];
*thirdYear = firstThree[2];

// PY2014 = (int*)calloc(*firstYear, sizeof(int));

for (i = 0; i < firstThree[0]; i++) {
    fscanf(fp, "%d", (PY2014 + i));
}
...
```

---

#### Some other Points

Also you had no error checking when you opened a file. It should be like this

```
...
FILE *fp = fopen(myFile, "r");
if( fp == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr,"%s\n","Error in opening file");
    exit(1);
}
...
```

I am not sure if you are aware of this but if you compile your program and then you try to run it like this

```
./a.out input.txt
   ^        ^
   |        |
  argv[0]   argv[1]
```

---

<sup>Same with `calloc`/`malloc` - check whether they returned `NULL` or something else. If `malloc` returns NULL and you try to access it then it's undefined behavior.(Your program will crash saying seg fault mostly)</sup>

---

#### Passing an array can be much more easier like this

In `main()`

```
...
readFile(argv[1], firstYear, secondYear, thirdYear, init4);

...
printf("thirdYear : %d\n", *thirdYear);

for (int i = 0; i < *firstYear; i++) {
    printf("PY2014: %d\n", init4[i]); //<-- change here.
}
```

In other function you don't need to change anything. (Other than commenting that `calloc`).

#### Few points

1. When indexing into array check whether the indices correspond to the correct position which is within the size of the array. (You didn't do any error checking- what happens when `*firstYear = 11`?)
2. Check the return value of the functions. That solves many problems halfway even before run into one.

Answer (score 0):

The code is pretty messy overall, but what is causing your problem is the scope of  the variable `PY2014` that you are passing to readFile:
The function is getting a pointer, you could change the data to which it is pointing but not the pointer itself (it will have no effect outside the funcion). 
In the line `PY2014 = (int*)calloc(*firstYear, sizeof(int));` and the in the for loop

```
for (i = 0; i < firstThree[0]; i++) {
    fscanf(fp, "%d", (PY2014 + i));
}
```

you are using `PY2014` as a local variable, therefore it will work fine inside the function but not outside.